# Writing to TextCtrl widget of wxPython while recieving data ( TCP )

Tags: wxpython

I am facing some issues writing received data from a TCP connection to TextCtrl ( using wxPython )

I have a thread with a while loop that waits for data that is received from users:

```
 def run(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                # receive
                data = self.channel.recv(1024)
            except socket.error, msg:
                if 'timed out' in msg:
                    continue

            if data:
                wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, ResultEvent('[' + self.username + ']>> ' + data + '\n'))

                self.text.AppendText(data+"")
```

notify_window is the my main frame, each connection has a MDIChildFrame, for each ChildFrame I attach TextCtrl to show the received data.

1. if I change the Title of the ChildFrame ( of specific connection ) , e.g window.SetTitle("..") everything works fine.
2. if I append text to some TextCtrl -> in this issue the TextCtrl of the ChildFrame my application hangs.
3. As you can see the wx.PostEvent(...) works fine it prints all the data to one TextCtrl. but this TextCtrl is created when I create the MainFrame instance and not dynamically like the other.

I tried to use wx.CallAfter in the while loop that receives the data but it does not help.
Has someone faced this issue?
thanks!

Notes:

I modified the example in: [pychatroom](https://code.google.com/p/pychatroom/source/browse/trunk/+pychatroom/) -  the server.py

the Class that from I writing to TextCtrl is ClientThread

Answer (score 1):

The text object (self.text) in the WorkerThread and all it's associated code should be moved to it's own frame object.

Part of the problem is that the WorkerThread is a thread class and not a wx.Window class, therefore it will not support the functionality of showing and updating a text control.

A bit of background...the general framework is that you will have a new WorkerThread for each child window and at the point you create the new child window you will create a new thread and bind the events for the new thread to the new window.  The PostEvent method will communicate data from the receiving thread to the child window.  It's good practice to never mix the wx GUI method calls with your thread objects.

The reason for this approach is keep the communicating threads separate from the main GUI thread which prevents your application interface from "hanging" and keeps everything repainted and updated properly.

Comment: I added the full code. if you need some the client version , visit the link I added there is client.py. let me know if its work for you.

Comment: Can you give me example that I can create child frame and send him events from the mainframe?